# What is the critical path in the design?

Tags: digital-logic, adder

I am trying to understand the worst case path in the 16bit carry bypass adder. Isn't the critical path through all the adders in the design?

[image]

But the solution is shown as below, how can it be the critical path(orange line)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Where did these diagrams come from? If the white trapezoids are meant to be ordinary 2:1 multiplexers, then this is not a correct implementation of a carry-bypass adder. The carry input to each 4-bit stage needs to be the logical OR of the mux output and the carry output of the previous stage.

The actual longest path through the whole design is from the inputs of the first stage (on the left) to the *sum* output of the 16th stage (on the right), following most of the orange path, but not through the final mux.

The logic after each stage should look like this:

$$C_{o,stage} = C_{i,n}\cdot P_{n}\cdot P_{n+1}\cdot P_{n+2}\cdot P_{n+3} + C_{o,n+3}$$

Comment: I was referring to the slides here: http://web.mit.edu/6.111/www/f2005/handouts/L12.pdf

Comment: I see. The "Key Idea" on slide 11 is simply wrong. It completely ignores the possibility that a carry will be generated inside the 4-bit stage *even if* all of the P bits are set! This makes the "Message" on slide 13 particularly ironic...

Comment: I still don't understand the orange path concept here. Considering that all adders in every stage waits on the carry from the previous stage, isn't that the worst case scenario?

Comment: Note that the critical path has been corrected in the [current version of the handout](http://web.mit.edu/6.111/www/f2016/handouts/L08.pdf) (page 18), but the "Key Idea" error remains (page 16). I'm trying to figure out who to contact at MIT about this.

Comment: No, the middle stages can be bypassed, because their P bits are generated long before the carry output of the first stage is available. If the P bits in an intermediate stage are not all set, then the carry output of the first stage does not matter, and the carry output of that intermediate stage is guaranteed to be *faster* than the one from the first stage, because of the delay introduced by the muxes.

Comment: Yes I understand that the P of the intermediate stages will be evaluated before the first stage carry is available. If the P bits of intermediate are not set to one, then there is no bypass possible right? Now the first adder in second stage should use the Co,3 generated from first stage and ripple through all the adder in its stage and similarly for 3rd stage, till the sum output in last stage. So the worst case path is through all the adders and muxes in every stage. isn't it?

Comment: No, because if *any P bit is not set* in a 4-bit stage, then the carry input will NOT propagate to the output! That's the very definition of what a P bit means. The carry output of that stage will depend only on its own A and B inputs, but not the carry input.

Comment: Thank you Dave,it took some time for me to understand the critical path logic. I got the logic behind the orange path now.